# gulp-ruby-sass Error handling

Tags: sass, pipe, gulp

Does anyone have any idea how you would handle errors in gulp-ruby-sass. I have noticed that it outputs directly to console when there is an error, but I would like to handle it myself.

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(sources.sass.files)
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))
    .pipe(
        plugins.rubySass({
            lineNumbers: true,
            style: 'expanded',
            sourcemap: true,
            sourcemapPath: '../../dev/sass'
        })
    )
    .on("error", function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(sources.sass.dest));
});
```

As you can see, I am trying two different ways to handle my error here but neither of them work. If I try `.on("error", console.log('error'))` that works, but it tells me the 'listener must be a function'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a package I published, `pipe-error-stop` as follows:

```
pipeErrorStop = require('pipe-error-stop');

// in the task
.pipe(pipeErrorStop(rubySass()))
```

If `rubySass` emits an error, no data will be passed onward further down the pipe. This prevents you from making a syntax error in your sass and finding a stack trace on your home page.

`pipeErrorStop` has callbacks that you can use to hook into, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gulp-plumber` might help you, have a look at this [blogpost](http://cameronspear.com/blog/how-to-handle-gulp-watch-errors-with-plumber) !

It would allow you do:

```
var onError = function (err) {  
  // whatever you need to do
};

gulp.task('styles', function () {  
  gulp.src('scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: onError
    }))
    .pipe(rubysass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: I have gulp-plumber already in that example, and unfortunately it doesn't work. :( It doesn't call the error handler.

Comment: Okay, it does work but the error handler only gets passed `undefined`.

Comment: From the [sources](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/blob/master/index.js#L100) it seems that the plugin handles errors internaly

Comment: Just what I was afraid of :(

Comment: Have you tried using the `trace` option ? It might give you a better understanding of why it fails (but in the standard output unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify/issues/37#issuecomment-48457930

Issue has been fixed by another GitHub user.